# Add 2008 R2 Secondary DC to 2003 Domain

Tags: active-directory

I'm having a hard time finding just a step-by-step solution here. I want to add a 2008 R2 server to an existing 2003 run domain. I want the 2008 server to allow for AD authentication logon incase the main 2003 DC goes down.

Most I've done is migration and just follow the steps that Microsoft outlines to migrate to 2003 to 2008. I've done a ton of those.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Add the 2008 R2 server to the domain as a member server
2. Prepare the 2003 DC using [the instructions found here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd464018(v=ws.10).aspx)
3. Run `dcpromo` on the new 2008 R2 machine and add it as another DC in the domain with a copy of the global catalog and DNS
4. Configure your clients to use this server as a secondary DNS server
5. Go have a sandwich

Comment: Step 4 is the most important step here.

Comment: good instructions, but where is the profit?

Comment: @longneck The profit is in the sandwich.

Comment: Do I got do the schema upgrade on the 2003 box?

Comment: Yes, you must prepare the schema for 2008 R2 by following the [very thorough and complete](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731728(v=ws.10).aspx) [documentation on TechNet if you haven't already.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd464018(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: Just to be clear about the important things, here. This answer was edited, point 4 used to refer to the sandwich.